# I applied ajax on menu content it is only working on first element in a loop not on others inside a modal when i press dorpdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've a scenario where I have created a **Menu** blade for the 
    **Restaurant Management System***. The Menu definitely have different 
    **Dishes** and Each Dish have different **Ingredients** and different 
    **Addons** as well, which is showing using Loop No doubt. when I press 
    edit button of addons a modal appears, Now the Modal contains Dropdown 
    element and 2 Input fields as well. When I select a dropdown 
    item in that modal it will fetch me relevent information and show it in 
    following input fields. I am using change function of jquery on dropdown 
    using Ajax. The Ajax is only working on first modal element not on 
    other's dishes addons and ingredients elements in the loop.Please guide 
    me what i'm doing wrong or what could be the proper way to do this.

```
I have asked this question on stakoverflow before and apply relevent 
solution generated dynamic classes on modal element so uniqueness remain
```

,but same issue persist.

``````
````Modal section````

````start loop````

<div class="modal fade getid" data-id="{{$item['id']}}"  id="editaddon-{{$item['id']}}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h1>{{$item['id']}}</h1>
                <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" >
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <h4 class="form-section"><i class="ft-user"></i>Dish Addon form</h4>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-3 label-control" for="projectinput6">Addons Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <select  name="dish_addon"   class="form-control selectaddon-{{$item['id']}}">
                                    <option value="none" selected >Select Menu</option>
                                    @foreach($add_items as $add_item)
                                    @if($add_item['dish_id']==$item['id'])
                                    <option value="{{$add_item['id']}}">{{$add_item['name']}}</option>
                                    @endif
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{route('update.dish.addon',$addon->id)}}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <h4 class="form-section"><i class="ft-user"></i>Dish Addon form</h4>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-3 label-control" for="projectinput1">Addon Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text"  value="" class="form-control addname-{{$item['id']}}" placeholder="Addon Name"
                                    name="name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-3 label-control" for="projectinput2">Addon Price</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <input type="text"  value="" class="form-control addprice-{{$item['id']}}" placeholder="Addon Price"
                                    name="price">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <input type="text"  value="" class="form-control dishadd-{{$item['id']}}" placeholder="Addon Price"
                                    name="add">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="la la-check-square-o"></i> Save
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            ````the Ajax method below is in blade script file```

            @include('dish.dish_script')
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`````end loop````
`````Ajax Section````

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var x=jQuery('.getid').attr('data-id');
console.log(x);
jQuery('.selectaddon-'+x).change(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '<?php echo csrf_token() ?>'
}
});
jQuery.ajax({
url: "{{ route('edit.dish.addon') }}",
method: 'post',
data: {
dish_addon: jQuery('.selectaddon-'+x).val(),
},
dataType:'JSON',
success: function(result){
if( result.success == 'true')
{
var data = result.data;
$('.addname-'+x).val(data.name);
$('.addprice-'+x).val(data.price);
$('.dishadd-'+x).val(data.id);
}
}
});
});
});
``````

`````end Ajax````

Comment: When you say ajax is not working, Did you check the console for any error? worth checking network if any ajax happening. Is your debugger hitting the ajax call? you should look for the answer to these question, this may guide you towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel modal loads only last entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930280/laravel-modal-loads-only-last-entry)